# Bootstrap Jquery erro

Tags: jquery, html, css

Não estou a perceber porque recebo este erro. Eu já meti todos os scripts, e mesmo assim nada. Estive a ler que o Bootstrap 3.3.7 não deve funcionar, mas eu preciso dele para as minhas tabelas e etc .. alguém me pode ajudar ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o jquery antes do bootstrap

Comment: resolveu, obrigado !

Comment: Por favor, não adicione RESOLVIDO no titulo da pergunta, este site funciona diferente de fóruns, o "aceite" em uma das respostas já mostra que a duvida foi sanada.

Comment: mas eu não sei onde fica .. pode me dizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivo jQuery deve vir sempre antes de qualquer plugin que use jQuery.

Aliás, a ordem de códigos é fundamental em toda programação.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="datetime-picker.min.js"></script>
```

E por aí vai...

Comment: ahhhh, obrigado !

Comment: Se o ajudou, por favor marque como resolvido.

Comment: onde faço isso ? :p